# Connect polygons with gap without dissolve intersected polygons in QGis

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing

I want to close gaps between polygons that are not intersecting and without a barrier in between (like streets).

Is it possible to aggregate or connect neighboring polygons (or closing the gaps between) within 1 m distance and in the same time without dissolving directly adjacent ones?

It is important that edges remain at not relevant polygons.

[image]

Comment: There is already an image.
And as you can read above, i want to close the gaps between polygons within a given distance. There are small linear gaps between single buildings, so the polygons should be connected to each other.
Streets should be used as barriers.

Comment: What have you tried by so far?

Comment: Nope, thats something different. As you can see I dont want to dissolve them! Additionally, working with buffers would change the original structures.

Comment: Have you tried both the snapping processing tools in qgis ? "Snap geometries to layer" and "Snap points to grid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a try using v.clean from GRASS GIS algoritms, you can enable them in processing.

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/v.clean.html

You can set the threshold for snap tool with appropriate threshold in map units and vertex of one building will be snapped to the next building...
maybe you will need to manually correct where facades are not aligned.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Snap is working good enough. But the research area is too big to correct single phenomenons.
But still, I will use snap and will neglect small errors.